# Grafana: How to refer to 1 query from a multi-query panel? (shared queries)

Tags: grafana

I am trying to utilize the '[query sharing](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/panels/query-a-data-source/share-query/)' method in Grafana to setup all my queries in 1 panel - and then reference these via separate individual panels. Being able to do this is critical for my dashboard performance.

For this case I'm using the SimpleJSON datasource plugin and in my 'Query Panel' I have defined two individual queries. One query should be used by Panel 1 and the other by Panel 2.

However, when I select Panel 1 and set the data source to Dashboard, I am only able to reference both of the queries from my Query Panel - not one or the other. This seems counter-intuitive, so I'm hoping there is a way to specifically select queries per panel.

My Query Panel:
[image]

My Panel 1 (where I cannot select e.g. the query `all_variables` as I would like to):
[image]